# Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth UserInfo endpoint

Tags: oauth, owin, openid-connect

I am implementing an OAuth server using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.

I use the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions to setup AuthorizeEndpointPath and TokenEndpointPath.  It looks like there is no option for a UserInfoEndpointPath though.

The OAuthV2 spec does discuss this endpoint vaguely -

*[This specification does not define a resource owner profile
information API.  It is assumed that other APIs such as the SCIM API
[I-D.ietf-scim-api] or the OpenID Connect [OpenID.Core] UserInfo
Endpoint could be used for this purpose.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hunt-oauth-v2-user-a4c-05#section-1)*

So, is there no way to leverage OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to provide this endpoint? Would I have to make a separate MVC controller endpoint? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I assume one could wrap up the user info content with the token and return it, however, the token could get quite large if things like images were to be included in a user's profile. But I am definitely interested in why this doesn't seem to be included in the OWIN framework.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, as we are trying to connect an external application that needs this enpoint. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @IdrisLokhandwala honestly I don't remember sorry